# Formula for sequence of 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, and so on (non-geometric, non-arithmetic)

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have been trying to figure out a formula for the sequence:

0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4

It is not geometric and it is not arithmetic, I tried to apply these formulas, but of them are failing leading me to believe it is not arithmetic nor geometric, can this be possibe? Is there another type of sequence?

Arithmetic:

[image]

Geometric:

[image]

Comment: It is a sum of an arithmetic and a geometric series $a_n = (\frac12 n - \frac34) - \frac14(-1)^n$

Comment: @achillehui that's a really cool note thank you! I didn't realize it could be a sum of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about 
$a_n = \frac{n}{2}-\frac{(-1)^n-1}{-4}$

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n=\begin{cases}\frac{n}2&n\text{ even}\\\frac{n-1}2&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
or for a non-piecewise answer we have
$$a_n=\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor$$
$$a_n=\frac{n}2+\frac{(-1)^n-1}4$$

Comment: Or the "floor" (integer part) of $n/2$.

Comment: This is perfect answers thank you i'm learning a lot, like 'piecewise' and 'foor'. Thanks Peter and @nick

Answer (score 1):

I am perturbed by your question.  Typically, one learns the general concept of "infinite sequence", then "convergent sequence", and then the special cases of "arithmetic sequence" and "geometric sequence".  Where in the world would you get the idea that all sequences must be either "arithmetic" or "geometric"?  The "arithmetic" and "geometric" sequence are just a very tiny part of all sequences.

Comment: Thanks for this note, I actually forgot about that infinite/convergent. I just remembered geo and arith from elementary school haha.

Comment: @Noitidart there are infinitely many sequences. Some of interest are at [OEIS](https://oeis.org/)

Comment: Oh wow that's awesome site!! I just entered my squence from this question on that site and it gave me tons of info!